# Div disappears after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and JavaScript and I'm stuck at a point, so I need suggestions from the intelligent brains sitting out there. I have div which is shown to the user before he logs in.

```
<div id="login" class = "login">
<ul>
  <li><a href="signup.html">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to replace this div with another div, which is hidden initially, after the user logs in successfully.

Div to be replaced with:

```
<div id="welcomelogin" class = "login" style="display: none;">
<ul>
  <li><a href="profile.html">Welcome abc</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am doing the following in my jQuery (right now I have hardcoded username/password values just to explain my problem).

I am calling auth function on a login button click. After the user clicks the login button, I want the page to reload and the #login div to be replaced with the #welcomeLogin div, so that the new url is shown to the user. But the problem is that the #welcomeLogin div does show up for few seconds, and then goes away because I have `location.reload` in place.

I also want the page to reload after authentication is successful, and then show the #welcomeLogin div until session remains. All this is done outside `$( document ).ready();`

```
function auth() {
    var userName = $("#login-username").val();
    var password = $("#login-password").val();

    if (userName == 'abc@xyz.com' && password == '12345') {
        location.reload();
        $("#login").hide();
        if (sessionStorage) {

            $("#welcomeLogin").show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to say, using Javascript to make login / authentification is pretty bad. Anyone can see your password in your page source code. Hoping your are using a service.

Comment: `if(userName=='abc@xyz.com' && password=='12345'){` does not have closing `}`? or it s a typo?

Comment: @VincentDecaux: I know it is bad to authenticate in JS, this is just to explain the problem. Ideally the authentication will be done at the server side and a true or false value will be sent back to the client. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ShaunakD: Thats just a typo.

Comment: @all Apologies for any poor wording used. I actually want to achieve the functionality exactly like stackoverflow.com itself. When you are on the homepage and then you log into the site the page reloads but you still remain on the home page after you have successfully logged in and the links on the top of the page gets replaced with your name and the session gets created. How can i replace the header urls with welcome message after the page reloads but i still remain the same page in my application.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `location.reload()`, the page refreshes. That means anything else on the client (i.e. any proceding javascript) *may* have time to run, but it's only because of the time the browser takes in refreshing the page.

You may call this javascript function on page load, and monitor some sort of state if you wish to seemingly 'persist' some change of DOM (swapping of divs, for example) to the next 'version' of the page.

I'd like to follow up with a recommended (alternative) way of doing this in javascript, but quite honestly I'm not sure it's the best approach at all for authentication.

I'd recommend a form post, and there are already available components for implementing form-based authentication depending on what you have on the server.

Comment: Actually it wont be dismissed. All javascript will be executed until the end. The user may see any changes until the browser reloads the page. But it is true it cannot be relied on. An ajax request, at that point, may never be executed.

Comment: I've worded this terribly, I meant dismissed as soon as the page reloads, I'll try and reword it...

Comment: [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ss1c9sor/) is a fiddle if you are right then second alert wont work yeap ?or i miss something, or i misunderstand you

Comment: @The - I've caused confusion poorly down to a poor choice of wording, please see updated answer.

Comment: Apologies if there is any confusion due to poor choice of words i am restating my requirement here. On my website i have link <a href="Signin.html">Login</a>. After i click on this link login form appears and i submit the form to do the authentication on the server side and send back true or false response to the client. If true the page should reload and user session should be created the login link should be replaced with the Welcome ABC. I can handle the session creation but i need to know how can i replace the login link with the Welcome text.

Answer (score 1):

After you refesh you page, everything goes to the very begining. your auth function will stop then and every js file are reloaded.